# USB Drive unmountable, disks won't start

Tags: usb, mount, delete

My USB drive won't mount. Not only that, but gnome-disks won't start until the drive is removed (from both terminal and gui launch, if that matters any). I've tried overwriting it with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=4096 count=4096` which I let run for about five minutes until it exited with `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdd': No medium found` at which point I couldn't see it even from `lsblk`, although `lsblk -a` gives

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 109.3G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk /media/user/Library
sdc      8:32   0 335.4G  0 disk /media/user/Media Backup
sdd      8:48   1         0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0    7:0    0         0 loop 
loop1    7:1    0         0 loop 
loop2    7:2    0         0 loop 
loop3    7:3    0         0 loop 
loop4    7:4    0         0 loop 
loop5    7:5    0         0 loop 
loop6    7:6    0         0 loop 
loop7    7:7    0         0 loop
```

This issue exists on every device I've tried, which are Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (where the problem began), MacOS (Sierra maybe?), Windows 7 Pro, and even Android with an OTG adapter. Nothing I've tried works. Can I overwrite or destroy and wipe clean the drive, or is it destined to be a very small paperweight? Thanks.

Removing the device, plugging it back in, and running `lsblk` gives

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 109.3G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk /media/user/Library
sdc      8:32   0 335.4G  0 disk /media/user/Media Backup
sdd      8:48   1  57.9G  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   1   1.4G  0 part 
└─sdd2   8:50   1   2.3M  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

where sdd is my drive, and that's the same output it's given despite multiple attempts at overwriting.

Comment: What kind of USB drive is it? If it is a USB pendrive, well, it is more likely damaged beyond repair, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297, but maybe still possible to recover, if you wipe confusing data from the first megabyte. If it is a USB hard disk drive or SSD, it might be possible to save. The damage might be in the USB interface, and inside the box you might find a working drive with a SATA interface, that you can use internally or in another external USB (or eSATA) box.

Comment: @sudodus I'm afraid it's a pendrive. Not the news I was hoping for, although I'm still going to go through the guide you linked to and try all that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Good luck :-) The tip to disconnect all other USB devices helps in some situations, but try the other tips too.